# Can CSP(Communicating sequential processes) parser be generated using ANTLR?

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, antlr, grammar, antlr3

Can I write a parser for Communicating sequential processes(CSP) in ANTLR? I think it uses left recursion like in statement

```
VMS = (coin → (choc → VMS))
```

complete language specification can be found at [CSPM : A Reference Manua](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/ucs/cspm.pdf)
so it is not a LL grammer. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, even if you have a grammar with left recursion, you can refactor the grammar to remove it.  So ANTLR is reasonably likely to be able to process your grammar.   There's no a priori reason you can't write a CSP grammar for ANTLR.

Whether the one you have is suitable is another question.

If your quoted phrase is a grammar rule, it doesn't have left recursion. (If it is, I don't understand the syntax of your grammar rules, especially why the parentheses [terminals?] would be unbalanced; that's pretty untradional.)
So ANTLR should be able to process it, modulo converting it to ANTRL grammar rule syntax.

You didn't show the rest of the grammar, so one can't have an opinion about the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks yo for your answer. I have edited question to ad link to language reference, the language i am parsing.

Comment: If you understand left recursion, it should be easy for you to check the grammar yourself.

Comment: ... if you read the langauge reference manual, the author even says that you can get a free, implemented parser in C++ that builds ASTs.  I'd start there; if nothing else, it will have a complete, tested grammar.

Answer (score 1):

In the case above does not have left recursion. It would looks something like. Note this is a simplified version, CSP is much more complicated.  I'm just showing it is possible.

```
assignment : PROCNAME EQ process
           ;
process : LPAREN EVENT ARROW process RPAREN
        | PROCNAME
        ;
```

Besides, you can factor out left recursion with ANTLRWorks 'Remove Left Recursion' function.

Comment: Although the _'Remove Left Recursion'_ functionality only works with the most trivial cases: I've never seen it work properly. Best just do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

CSP's are definitely possible in ANTLR, check http://www.carnap.info/ for an example.

Comment: The link became probably invalid - it doesn't help any more